# Join R data.tables where key values are not exactly equal--combine rows with closest times

Tags: r, time, data.table

Is there a slick way to join data tables in R where key values of time are close, but not exactly the same? For example, suppose I have a data table of results that are given for different time periods:

```
DT1 = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), time=c(10,30,60), v=1:9)
```

Here, we have some values (v) for different categories (x) taken at different times (time). Now suppose that I have data from another source that provides some time values for the different categories:

```
DT2=data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=1),time=c(10,10,60))
```

I might be interested in trying to match the times in DT2 as closely as I can to DT1 to predict a value, v, for my DT2 categories. I would like to do something like

```
setkeyv(DT2,c("x","time"))
merge(DT1,DT2,by=c("time","v")
```

Which returns:

```
   time x v
1:   10 a 1
2:   10 b 4
3:   60 c 9
```

But what if my times didn't have the same precision? For example:

```
DT2=data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=1),time=c(17,54,3))
```

Is there a way to perform a similar merge but pick times of DT2 that are close to those of DT1? That is 17 would be close to 30, 54 close to 60, and 3 close to 10?

If this simple example isn't clear, I'll briefly explain the larger problem that I am having. I have a data table with columns: category, time, output1, output2... There are hundreds of categories with associated times. I might want to pull output 1 for all categories at a specific time. Since the times were sampled with no apparent logic, sometimes the time is rounded to the nearest even second; in other cases the times are rounded to the nearest minute or even 10 minutes.

I could write a script to rewrite times in more common format, but I am curious if there is a slick data.table solution that I haven't seen. I have explored the rolling merge with no success.

Comment: Try merge(..., all=TRUE) and sum the like rows to your liking.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Another option may be `roll='nearest'` (new in v1.8.8 on CRAN).

```
> setkey(DT1,x,time)
> DT1
   x time v
1: a   10 1
2: a   30 2
3: a   60 3
4: b   10 4
5: b   30 5
6: b   60 6
7: c   10 7
8: c   30 8
9: c   60 9
> DT2
   x time
1: a   17
2: b   54
3: c    3
> DT1[DT2,roll="nearest"]
   x time v
1: a   17 1
2: b   54 6
3: c    3 7
```

Note that 17 appears to be closer to 10 than 30, hence the result in the first row.

If you need to roll to the next observation (next observation carried backwards) :

```
> DT1[DT2,roll=-Inf]
   x time v
1: a   17 2
2: b   54 6
3: c    3 7
```

Comment: would it also be possible to add a column for the differences in time between the data.tables? E.g. 10-17 = -7 or abs(10-17) = 7.

If one for instance want to exlclude values that are joined more than 5 steps apart or want to evaluate the effect of time apart.

Comment: @EndreGrünerOfstad  Limiting staleness is built in to `roll`: passing in a number limits the staleness to that value (hence `Inf` is no limit).  See `?data.table`, the presentations, and chapter 10 of the DataCamp data.table course.  You can also use `x.` and `i.` prefix to extract the difference explicitly in j, e.g. `x.time-i.time`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `findInterval` to accomplish this:

```
setkey(DT2, time)
DT1[, id := findInterval(DT1$time, DT2$time)]
DT2[, id := 1:3]

setkey(DT1, "x", "id")
setkey(DT2, "x", "id")
print(DT1[DT2][, id := NULL])
#    x time v time.1
# 1: a   30 2     17
# 2: b   60 6     54
# 3: c   10 7      3
```

The idea: First sort the data.table by time because the second argument of `findInterval` requires increasing order of values. Now, use `findInterval` to find in which interval of `3, 17, 54` does the values in `DT1$time` fall and store it in `id`. In this particular case, it happens to range from 1 to 3. So, set these values as `id` column for `DT2`. Once you find the intervals and get `id`, then it's straightforward. Instead of setting `x` and `time`, set `x` and `id` as keys and do your merge.

**Note:** Suppose your `DT1$time` had a value of 0, then, the interval for that would have been 0. So, you'd get 4 unique values (0:3). In that case, it may be better to have DT2 with a time = 0 value as well. I just wanted to note this point here. I'll leave it to you.

Comment: Fantastically helpful answer. Thank you for providing a great solution as well as a helpful explanation.

Comment: +1!  Brilliant method.   Minor suggestion to allow for generalization:  perhaps use `DT2[, id := as.numeric(factor(time))]` instead of explicit id.  or `DT2[, id := seq(nrow(DT2))]` if not allowing for duplicate time values