# labelling rows in one data set based on the date of the measurement compared to two other dates in another dataset

Tags: r, date, split, data.table

```
library(data.table)
testset <- data.table(date=as.Date(c("2013-07-02","2013-08-03","2013-09-04",
                                     "2013-10-05","2013-11-06")), 
                      yr = c(2013,2013,2013,2013,2013), 
                      mo = c(07,08,09,10,11),
                      da = c(02,03,04,05,06), 
                      plant = LETTERS[1:5], 
                      product = as.factor(letters[26:22]), 
                      rating = runif(25))
```

I have this dataset that for each row I want to create a category or naming on that row depending on the date column. I want to compare this date with dates in another dataset:

```
library(lubridate)
splitDates <- ymd(c("2013-06-10", "2013-08-15", "2013-10-06"))
```

Using splitDates I want to evaluate which value in splitDates came last before the measurement was taken. (If you imagine that a new experiment took place from 2013-06-10 and until but not including 2013-08-15, I want to decide what experiment a measurement belongs to).

As I can see the first five rows in this new column should look like this:

```
NewColumn <- c("2013-06-10", "2013-06-10", "2013-08-15", "2013-08-15", "2013-10-06")

         date   yr mo da plant product     rating  NewColumn
1: 2013-07-02 2013  7  2     A       z 0.02522850 2013-06-10
2: 2013-08-03 2013  8  3     B       y 0.28274066 2013-06-10
3: 2013-09-04 2013  9  4     C       x 0.86314441 2013-08-15
4: 2013-10-05 2013 10  5     D       w 0.01670862 2013-08-15
5: 2013-11-06 2013 11  6     E       v 0.16034175 2013-10-06
...
```

I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: if i understand correctly, the values always come from the `splitDates`

Comment: `testset[, v := splitDates[findInterval(date, splitDates)]]` seems to work? Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15712826/

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take

```
library(dplyr)
dta <- data.frame(NewColumn=splitDates,newvar=1:3)
testset$newvar <- sapply(testset[,1], function(x) ifelse(x<splitDates[2],1,ifelse(x<splitDates[3],2,3)))
final_data <- semi_join(testset,dta,by="newvar")
```

Data:

```
testset <- data.table(date=as.Date(c("2013-07-02","2013-08-03","2013-09-04",
                                 "2013-10-05","2013-11-06")), 
                  yr = c(2013,2013,2013,2013,2013), 
                  mo = c(07,08,09,10,11),
                  da = c(02,03,04,05,06), 
                  plant = LETTERS[1:5], 
                  product = as.factor(letters[26:22]), 
                  rating = runif(25))

splitDates <- ymd(c("2013-06-10", "2013-08-15", "2013-10-06"))
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, understanding your question was more difficult than solving it. Please review the answer, and give me a feedback. It has 3 steps:

1. make a function to return the latest date from the other dataset

   ```
   findLatest<-function(date){which.min( abs(  splitDates-date  ))}
   ```
2. Then call the function over all the dates in `testset`:

   ```
   names<-splitDates[ sapply(testset[,1], findLatest  ) ]
   ```
3. Add the result to the dataset

   ```
   testset$names<-names
   ```

So, the first 10 rows are:

```
         date   yr mo da plant product     rating         V8
1  2013-07-02 2013  7  2     A       z 0.75801493 2013-06-10
2  2013-08-03 2013  8  3     B       y 0.06370597 2013-08-15
3  2013-09-04 2013  9  4     C       x 0.25375231 2013-08-15
4  2013-10-05 2013 10  5     D       w 0.42900236 2013-10-06
5  2013-11-06 2013 11  6     E       v 0.97613291 2013-10-06
6  2013-07-02 2013  7  2     A       z 0.78094927 2013-06-10
7  2013-08-03 2013  8  3     B       y 0.91312684 2013-08-15
8  2013-09-04 2013  9  4     C       x 0.29345599 2013-08-15
9  2013-10-05 2013 10  5     D       w 0.80870134 2013-10-06
10 2013-11-06 2013 11  6     E       v 0.18735280 2013-10-06
```

Comment: I get the error  names<-splitDates[ sapply(testset[,1], findLatest  ) ]
Advarselsbesked:
I unclass(time1) - unclass(time2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
I like the logic behind the solution. However already in the second row of your output the V8 value is after the date, which shouldn't be possible considering V8 is "the initiation of the experiment and the date is the value of result of that experiment"

Comment: sorry what is the error on `names<-splitDates[ sapply(testset[,1], findLatest ) ]`?
Did you load the `findLatest ` beforehand?

Comment: Yes I did. It just means warning in Danish.

Answer (score 0):

I have to hand the answer to Frank, which commented on my first post.

```
testset[, v := splitDates[findInterval(date, splitDates)]]
```

does the trick.

Comment: I admire this solution as well. But, it is not good to use @Frank comment as a your own solution. Maybe you can make it as community.

Comment: Also, although it is short, i cannot fully understand how it works

Comment: me neither. I have not used as a solution, but hope Frank will come and claim it. I created a new entry to make it easier for others to find the answer.