# Is it possible to merge two .csv files to the nearest hour?

Tags: r, merge, temporal-database

I have two .csv files called 'tag.csv' and 'wind.csv' that I would like to merge based on the 'Date' column. However, as you can see from the data below the times do not match exactly.

tag.csv

```
Date
13/12/2014 05:11
13/12/2014 05:43
13/12/2014 06:34
```

wind.csv

```
Date
13/12/2014 05:00
13/12/2014 06:00
13/12/2014 07:00
```

I am using the following simple script.

```
tag<- read.csv("tag.csv")
wind<- read.csv("wind.csv")
myfulldata = merge(tag, wind)
```

Is there a command I could add so that the data will merge with the closest time? For example, 13/12/2014 05:11 will merge with 13/12/2014 05:00

Comment: Maybe showing your expected output will make this question clear.

Comment: There are all sorts of questions here. Can you guarantee a 1-1 match? If not, do you want the `tag` to match to the nearest `wind`, or the `wind` to the nearest tag? Would it be enough to just round the times to the nearest hour, then merge? Since your sample data doesn't include any other info, it makes it difficult to tell what is merged with what - a better example would have 1 other column for each input and then show the expected output.

Comment: I would like the wind to match the tag but, I think your suggestion of rounding to the nearest hour will be the quickest way around the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.table` package has its own merging method and an option called `roll` that allows closest matches. e.g.

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(a = c(1,2,3,4), b=1:4)
dt2 <- data.table(a = c(1.6,2.1,3.2,4.9), c=1:4)
setkeyv(dt1, "a")
setkeyv(dt2, "a")
dt1[dt2, roll="nearest"]
```

See [Join R data.tables where key values are not exactly equal--combine rows with closest times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712826/join-r-data-tables-where-key-values-are-not-exactly-equal-combine-rows-with-clo) for another example.

To be robust though, I would probably instead do some datetime manipulation to force them to both be to the nearest hour, and then do a nearest join if all else fails

edit: this method won't work on `data.frame` objects, if you haven't used `data.table` before maybe stay simple and round the hours