# Fuzzyjoin left_join on two columns

Tags: r

I have two datasets I want to join in a Shiny application

Both have two columns- dates and alphanumeric strings that the user chooses

eg The format of the columns is the same in the two dataframes ie:

```
EndoNum   EndoDate         PathNum   PathDate        
F321321  13/12/2001       F321321  21/12/2001
```

I want to left join dataset one with dataset two but the dates are out by between 1-8 days

I have tried from `fuzzyjoin`:

```
        EndoDate<-colnames(RV$data[as.numeric(input$endotable_columns_selected[1])])
        EndoNum<-colnames(RV$data[as.numeric(input$endotable_columns_selected[2])])
        PathDate<-colnames(RV2$data[as.numeric(input$endotable_columns_selected[1])])
        PathNum<-colnames(RV2$data[as.numeric(input$endotable_columns_selected[2])])


  difference_left_join(RV2$data,
                          RV$data,
                          by=setNames(nm=c(EndoNum,EndoDate),c(PathNum,PathDate)),
                          max_dist = 8,
                          distance_col = "Days"
     )
```

but I get the error: `Error in v1 - v2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

How can I make the join. Do I have to use fuzzyjoin?

Comment: Might be somethings you could try here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712826/join-r-data-tables-where-key-values-are-not-exactly-equal-combine-rows-with-clo

Comment: Unfortunately that doesnt let me specify a number of days to match over just the nearest...