# Mapping and assigning values between columns of different lengths using R

Tags: r

I got a df such as this

```
structure(list(id = c(4375, 4375, 4375, 4375), time = c(0, 88, 
96, 114)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

and a second df (df2) such as this

```
structure(list(id2 = c(4375, 4375, 4375, 4375, 4375, 4375, 4375, 
4375, 4375, 4375), time2 = c(0, 2, 87, 88, 94, 97, 101, 104, 
109, 114), score2 = c(0.028, 0.057, 0.057, 0.057, 0.057, 0.057, 
0.057, 0.085, 0.085, 0.085)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

I want for each id, to map the time column in both df and creating a score column in df1 and assigning the value of score from df2, when the time value in df1 is equal or less than the time in df2.
I want the final df to look like this

```
structure(list(id3 = c(4375, 4375, 4375, 4375), time3 = c(0, 
88, 96, 116), score3 = c(0.028, 0.057, 0.057, 0.085)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: I don't understand is your final output correct? 116? Could you please clarify!

Comment: Sorry that should be 114

Comment: I think there's a previous question covering this, but you could do a rolling join in data.table too - `library(data.table); setDT(df1); setDT(df2); df2[df1, on=c("id2"="id","time2"="time"), roll=+Inf, .(id, time, score2)]`

Comment: E.g. - this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712826/join-r-data-tables-where-key-values-are-not-exactly-equal-combine-rows-with-clo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could do it with `fuzzyjoin` to handle near matches:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)

fuzzy_left_join(df, df2, by = c("time"="time2"), match_fun = list(`<=`)) %>% 
  group_by(time2) %>% 
  slice(n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(time) %>% 
  filter(row_number()==1) %>% 
  select(id3=id, time3=time, score3 = score2)
```

```
    id3 time3 score3
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1  4375     0  0.028
2  4375    88  0.057
3  4375    96  0.057
4  4375   114  0.085
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a way for a fuzzy join. Now I know. +1!

Comment: Nice to see you brother too :)

Comment: Always a pleasure my friend!

Answer (score 1):

For exact matches in the id and time columns, we can use `left_join`:

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df, df2, by=c('id'='id2', 'time'='time2'))

    id time score2
1 4375    0  0.028
2 4375   88  0.057
3 4375   96     NA
4 4375  114  0.085
```

However, as we can see, this wont handle near-matches well. Please define, what do you mean by " when the time value in df1 is equal or less than the time in df2.". equal or less than what? How do we match the elements for the "equal or less then" comparison?

Comment: Nice to see you brother :)